# How to delete certain cells from Numbers?

Tags: applescript, numbers, automation

So I have a large dataset with a lot of "noise" in it. I need to get rid of all these cells that have either "-999" in it or "888".

How can I programmatically do that using the numbers app so I am not doing this all day long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is one way to achieve what you are asking:

```applescript
tell application "Numbers"
    tell document 1
        tell sheet 1
            tell table 1
                set the targetCells to a reference to (cells whose value is -999)
                set the value of the targetCells to ""
                set the targetCells to a reference to (cells whose value is 888)
                set the value of the targetCells to ""
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

---

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Once I drop this script inside `Numbers` application in Finder, how do I execute it? I have no experience with AppleScript.

Comment: @Daniel, RE: "Once I drop this script inside `Numbers` application in Finder" -- You **do not** do that. -- As stated in the **Notes:** ... "was tested in **Script Editor**", which is the **macOS** default _app_ for writing, testing, running **AppleScript** _code_. Once you've modified/tested the _code_ to suit your specific needs, then there are a number of different ways to utilize the _code_. As an **AppleScript** _application_, a standalone _application_, or as an **AppleScript** _script_ triggered from the **Script** menu on the **menu bar**, or an **Automator** _Service/Quick Action_.

Comment: how did you test it? I copied it to my Script Editor and hit play and got `Expected end of line but found number.`. My version starts like this: `tell application "Numbers"
    tell document Altered_CALES_spreadsheet
        tell Data
            tell table 1` The table itself has no heading just the columns in the table do.

Comment: @Daniel, RE: "how did you test it? " -- I tested it as explained in the **Notes:** section of the answer, in **Script Editor**.  I also (obviously) had a **Numbers** _document_ opened in which I had populated many _cells_ with '-999- and '888' as well as other _numbers_, to verify my _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ worked!  -- Please have a look at [iWork Automation: Numbers AppleScript Support](https://iworkautomation.com/numbers/), as it is one of the better online resources for scripting **Numbers** with **AppleScript**.

Comment: @Daniel, I appreciate that you do not know/understand **AppleScript**, however, you asked **How to delete certain cells from Numbers?** and sans doing it manually, my answer provided an example of how to accomplish it programmatically, which is exactly what you asked for. You need to do some of the leg work to implement it, and the link in my previous comment is the best place to start.